# clarification of rails associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

While following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide I'm trying to plan out how to do proper rails associations for my application.

In plain English, I had a scaffold form for reviews, that must be created by a registered user. I want to make a concert model that has many reviews, if a review is created with an artist, venue, and date (all fields from review form) that has not already been done, a concert object will be created and this review will belong to it. However if a review is created with the same artist, venue, and date as a previous review, then this review will be added to the already existent concert object.

I would also like an Artist model that has many concerts and possibly has many reviews (though this seems unnecessary because reviews are contained within concerts).

From my understanding I would want to do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end

class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :concert
  has_one :concert, through => :artist #and review's venue and date?
end

class Concert < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :concerts
 end
```

and then I think I would need 4 different migration files and would need to make sure that they use `belongs_to` but not `has_many` or any of the other associations?

I just want to make sure I have a good general idea of the right associations based on what it is I'm trying to do. Any help or suggestions/feedback is appreciated, this is my first rails application, thank you.

Comment: Based on the plain English description of what type of relationships I want, is this the correct way to code it? and how would the has_one relationship work in Review for concert?

Answer (score 0):

A review belongs to a concert so in `Review` remove

```
has_one :concert, through => :artist
```

I'm not sure about your app enough but you might want `Review` to

```
has_one :artist through => :concert
```

though.  See [Rails Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).